# extract a substring where the characters next to it varies using regex in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have some strings like below. I need to extract color part from the strings.

```
s1=  'color: red greenSize: 2 CountVerified Purchase'
s2=  'color: red greenVerified Purchase'
s3=  'color: red greenSize: 2 Count'
s4=  'color: red green'
```

I used `str_replace` like below. It only works for `s1` and `s3`. Not for `s2` and `s4`.

```
str_replace(s1, 'color:\\s(.*)Size:\\s.*', '\\1')
```

Does anyone know how I can extract the colors from the string that work for ALL 4 cases?

Comment: Please give more detail. What is the expected output?

Comment: Also would it always have red and green as colors ? If not can you add some more examples with different colors.

Comment: @RonakShah Something against red and green `:P` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not really, but I want to feel inclusive to all colors.. :P

Answer (score 2):

These expressions might work:

```
color:\s(.*?)(Size.*|[A-Z].*|$)
color:\s(.*?)([A-Z].*|$)
```

and our code might look like,

```
str_replace(s1, 'color:\\s(.*?)([A-Z].*|$)', '\\1')
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/CYoGEC/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/IAHVXc/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt using `regmatches`, along with the following regex pattern:

```
color: (\\S+) (\\S+)(?=Size|Verified|$)
```

This isolates the first and second colors, the second color's end being given by either the words `Size` or `Verified`, of the end of the string.

```
x <- c("color: red greenSize: 2 CountVerified Purchase",
       "color: red greenVerified Purchase",
       "color: red greenSize: 2 Count",
       "color: red green")
sapply(x, function(x) {
    result <- regmatches(x, regexec("color: (\\S+) (\\S+)(?=Size|Verified|$)", x, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
    c(result[2], result[3])
})
```

This outputs (a bit messy):

```
     color: red greenSize: 2 CountVerified Purchase
[1,] "red"
[2,] "green"
     color: red greenVerified Purchase color: red greenSize: 2 Count
[1,] "red"                             "red"
[2,] "green"                           "green"
     color: red green
[1,] "red"
[2,] "green"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it just me or are all those colors in lowercase? If this happens to be the case, you could simply do:

```
pattern <- "color:\\s*([a-z ]+).*"
gsub(pattern, "\\1", your_strings_here)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6o3uLW/3/).

Comment: Actually, your answer followed by a call to `strsplit` on the first capture group to generate a list of all colors, is probably the best answer +1.